# How to skip value if it is correct without asking input again?

Tags: java

I am instructed to skip a value if it has been guessed correctly so that it can proceed to ask for the other value without being repeated. I am only beginning to learn Java and have yet to learn how to do this. I tried to search up how to skip the correct guessed value but could not find anything. Is there a way to do this? Thank you in advance.

```java
while (guessX != randomX || guessY != randomY) {
    System.out.print("Enter a guess for the X position of Mr. Yertle: ");
    guessX = scan.nextInt();
    if (guessX < randomX) {
        System.out.println("Too low! Guess higher.");
    } else if (guessX > randomX) {
        System.out.println("Too high! Guess lower.");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Ding, ding! You are correct!");
    }
    System.out.print("Enter a guess for the Y position of Mr. Yertle: ");
    guessY = scan.nextInt();
    if (guessY < randomY) {
        System.out.println("Too low! Guess higher.");
    } else if (guessY > randomY) {
        System.out.println("Too high! Guess lower.");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Ding, ding! You are correct!");
    }
```

Comment: put it into map, and check if value exists in first place

Comment: You could also use two separate while loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split them to 2 parts.

```java
while (guessX != randomX) {
    System.out.print("Enter a guess for the X position of Mr. Yertle: ");
    guessX = scan.nextInt();
    if (guessX < randomX) {
        System.out.println("Too low! Guess higher.");
    } else if (guessX > randomX) {
        System.out.println("Too high! Guess lower.");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Ding, ding! You are correct!");
    }
}
while (guessY != randomY) {
    System.out.print("Enter a guess for the Y position of Mr. Yertle: ");
    guessY = scan.nextInt();
    if (guessY < randomY) {
        System.out.println("Too low! Guess higher.");
    } else if (guessY > randomY) {
        System.out.println("Too high! Guess lower.");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Ding, ding! You are correct!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can break them into separate functions and check if you already has 1 correct value;

```
public static void feedback(int guess, int ans) {
    if (guess < ans) {
        System.out.println("Too low! Guess higher.");
    } else if (guess > ans) {
        System.out.println("Too high! Guess lower.");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Ding, ding! You are correct!");
    }
}

public static int takeInput(char c) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter a guess for the " + c + " position of Mr. Yertle: ");
    return scan.nextInt();
    
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int randomX = 10, randomY = 20;
    int guessX = 0, guessY = 0;
    
    while (guessX != randomX && guessY != randomY) {
        guessX = takeInput('X');
        feedback(guessX, randomX);
        
        guessY = takeInput('Y');
        feedback(guessY, randomY);
    }
    if(guessX == randomX) {
        while(guessY != randomY){
            guessY = takeInput('Y');
            feedback(guessY, randomY);
        }
    }
    else {
        while(guessX != randomX){
            guessX = takeInput('X');
            feedback(guessX, randomX);
        }
    }
}
```